# How to disable parent htaccess rules in a specific folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have an htaccess in the main folder. I don't want to apply the main htaccess to a specific folder inside the main folder.

```
--Main Folder
  .htaccess
  some folder
  another folder --> don't want htaccess to apply here
  some files
  ...
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Unless you have access to the server config, it depends what directives you need to "override" in the specific subdirectory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a one liner .htaccess in that specific folder where you don't want rules from main .htaccess to apply with:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Comment: Although this only applies to mod_rewrite directives. The OP hasn't actually stated what directives they have in the main `.htaccess` file.

Comment: When someone writes about  **rules**, prime suspect is `mod_rewrite` :)

Comment: ...very true :)

Comment: I am trying to use this solution but its not working.  the subdirectory is being blocked due to the primary .htaccess blocking access.  The primary .htaccess has a line: `Header set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self' *.myDomain.com"` that is block my app from loading an iFrame.  How can I override this in the sub-directory?

Comment: @anubhava Not necessarily. I have a `Redirect` from the parent which I need to deactivate in a child.